# How to use the onkeydown function to update celsius value in degree to farenheit converter

Tags: javascript, input

I decided to build a web utility that will help people do easy conversions from degrees to farenheit. Every html element on te page is rendering as expected, the only problem is the javascript...

***Methodology***

I used the javascript `onkeydown()` to register the method that will be responding to keyboard presses on the degrees input field. This function calls another function called `update()` that is supposed to get the input the user entered in the degrees field, process it and display the result in the farenheit field. Except that there seems to be a problem in the update function. I do not know if its the way am accessing the input fields properties and assigning...please help

***Code***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Degrees to Farenheit Converter
</title>
<!--add dependencies-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="materialize/css/materialize.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<center><h5>Convert Degrees to Farenheit</h5></center>
<center><h5>Temp in Degrees:</h5><input class="form-control"type="number" id="degrees" onkeydown="update()"/><br/></center>
<center><h5>Temp in Celsius</h5><input class="form-control"type="number"  id="farenheit"/></center>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
let degree=document.getElementbyId("degrees");
let far=document.getElementById("farenheit");
//iplement a function that will listen on text
//change inside the farenheit field
function update(){
//alert("a key was pressed");
//get the number and convert to farenheit
let temp=parseInt(degree.value);
//convert to farenheit and display in th other 
//boex  
let faren=1.8*temp+32;
//display the result in the celsius field
far.value=faren;
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Typo at: `getElementbyId`. This should cause an error to be printed in the console.

Comment: Owh, did not see that, THank You, please do not close yet as i try to see if its working and maybe edit and update the question

Comment: hey i tried to use the parseFloat instead of the parseInt() but code refuses to compile, why is this?

Comment: The `onkewdown()` function is inappropriate for this utility because it only calculates when a key is pressed, perhaps i should use the `onkeyup()` for the same and see what will happen?

Comment: @KINYUATIMOTHYNJIRU onKeyDown -> Event fire when user press key
onKeyUp -> Event fire when user stop press key

in this case onkeydown is better because user can keep key pressed and the values will be continue be calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is case-sensitive, and you write `document.getElementbyId()` when the right one is `document.getElementById()`

```js
let degree = document.getElementById("degrees");
let far= document.getElementById("farenheit");
//iplement a function that will listen on text
//change inside the farenheit field
function update(){
//alert("a key was pressed");
//get the number and convert to farenheit
let temp=parseInt(degree.value);
//convert to farenheit and display in th other 
//boex  
let faren=1.8*temp+32;
//display the result in the celsius field
far.value=faren;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<center><h5>Convert Degrees to Farenheit</h5></center>
<center><h5>Temp in Degrees:</h5><input class="form-control"type="number" id="degrees" onkeyup="update()"/><br/></center>
<center><h5>Temp in Celsius</h5><input class="form-control"type="number"  id="farenheit"/></center>
</div>
```